# Float to String conversion in android

Tags: java, android

i am trying simple calculation of float value but the output are not proper

```
Log.i("100/50", Float.toString(100/50));
Log.i("100/100", Float.toString(100/100));
Log.i("100/250", Float.toString(100/250));
Log.i("1/5", Float.toString(1/5));
```

logcat output

```
11-10 23:36:23.677: I/100/50(28562): 2.0
11-10 23:36:23.677: I/100/100(28562): 1.0
11-10 23:36:23.685: I/100/250(28562): 0.0
11-10 23:38:23.685: I/1/5(28562): 0.0
```

its a simple calculation of float, why its displaying such answer

Comment: how and what you want to display then?

Comment: @Software sainath For the 3rd one 100/250 = 0.04. The result above is o.0.

Comment: 100/250=0.4 & 1/5 =0.2 ,so how it is correct, why 0.0 ?

Comment: I think you're looking to get a floating point values in the log. You should be doing `Float.toString(100f/50)` instead of `Float.toString(100/50)`

Comment: Yeah You are doing Integer Division and result is definitely an integer and later you are casting to float thats why it is adding .0 to the int

Comment: ok thnak you all, all you are right,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use floats instead of ints, try `Log.i("100/50", Float.toString(100f/50));` this makes Java to use float arithmetic, otherwise it does int division then converts the result to float

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
Log.i("100/250", Float.toString(100f/250f));
Log.i("1/5", Float.toString(1f/5f));
```

output is

```
11-11 12:25:32.198: I/100/250(351): 0.4
11-11 12:25:32.208: I/1/5(351): 0.2
```

Float.toString takes an input floating point

```
public static String toString (float f)

where f is the float to convert to a string.
```

More information is available on [Developers Website](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Float.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

Log.i("100/50", Float.toString(100/50f));
Log.i("100/100", Float.toString(100/100f));
Log.i("100/250", Float.toString(100/250f));
Log.i("1/5", Float.toString(1/5f));

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing division of two integers. So by default output will be in integer. Instead of that try to type cast the dividend into float e.g. (float)100/250, so the output will be in float and you will get proper result.

E.g. instead of 100/250 try (float)100/250 or 100f/250.